# how many times repeat integer elements in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");

    int dizi[10]={9,30,3,6,9,20,3,6,10,9};
    int counter, j;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        counter=1;
        for(int j=i+1; j<10;  j++){
            if(dizi[i]==dizi[j+1]){
                counter++;
            }   
        }

        cout<<dizi[i]<<"\t:"<<counter<<endl;        
    }

}
```

```
   /*
   //THE RESULT
    9       :3   
    30      :1   
    3       :2   
    6       :2   
    9       :2   //WRONG I don't want this line to appear
    20      :1   
    3       :1   //WRONG I don't want this line to appear
    6       :1   //WRONG I don't want this line to appear
    10      :1   
    9       :1   //WRONG I don't want this line to appear
   */
```

Comment: Count the occurences first and store them in a table, without printing anything. Then print the table. Alternatively, you can keep track of which numbers you've already counted in a table, but that's messier.

Comment: Use a [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to count the elements

Comment: Insert an inner for loop before the j-for loop from 0 to i that tests, if we already summed up this number. Execute the j-for loop only, if not.

Comment: Alternatively disable the counted element (at counter++) by setting it to e.g. -1, skip the j-for loop, if you encounter -1

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the STL for such problems. Iterate over your array, count the occurence in `counts` and store the order in `order`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    int dizi[] = { 9, 30, 3, 6, 9, 20, 3, 6, 10, 9 };

    std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counts;
    std::vector<int> order;

    for (const auto &el : dizi) {
        if (counts.find(el) == counts.end()) order.push_back(el);
        ++counts[el];
    }

    for (const auto &el : order) {
        std::cout << el << "\t:" << counts[el] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9   :3
30  :1
3   :2
6   :2
20  :1
10  :1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int dizi[] = { 9, 30, 3, 6, 9, 20, 3, 6, 10, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( dizi ) / sizeof( *dizi );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j != i && dizi[j] != dizi[i] ) ++j;

        if ( j == i )
        {
            size_t counter = 1;

            while ( ++j != N )
            {
                if ( dizi[j] == dizi[i] ) ++counter;
            }

            std::cout << dizi[i] << ":\t" << counter << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9:  3
30: 1
3:  2
6:  2
20: 1
10: 1
```

That is you need to check whether a current value was already countered.

Comment: Holy algorithmic complexity, Batman! Also, prefer `std::size` to error-prone pointer trickery.